# How to pull link and put into an href?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have a website that I'm trying to populate with links. Right now, if you look at the website from the computer, you'll see that there's a floating box with text, then dots all over the map. If you hover over one of the dots, it will have the name of the site, along with the time period associated.

http://jeremynative.com/onthissite/

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $et_location_lat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_et_listing_lat', true );
    $et_location_lng = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_et_listing_lng', true );

    $et_location_rating = '<div class="location-rating"></div>';
    if ( ( $et_rating = et_get_rating() ) && 0 != $et_rating )
        $et_location_rating = '<div class="location-rating"><span class="et-rating"><span style="' . sprintf( 'width: %dpx;', esc_attr( $et_rating * 17 ) ) . '"></span></span></div>';

    if ( '' != $et_location_lat && '' != $et_location_lng ) {
?>




            et_add_marker( <?php printf( '%1$d, %2$s, %3$s, \'<div id="et_marker_%1$d" class="et_marker_info"><div class="location-description"> <div class="location-title"> <h2>%4$s </h2> <div class="listing-info"><p>%5$s</p></div> </div> ' . $et_location_rating . ' </div> <!-- .location-description --> </div> <!-- .et_marker_info -->\'',
                $i,
                esc_html( $et_location_lat ),
                esc_html( $et_location_lng ),
                get_the_title(),
                wp_strip_all_tags( addslashes( get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'listing_type', '', ', ' ) ) )
            ); ?> );
<?php
    }

    $i++;
endwhile;

rewind_posts();
?>
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How can I copy the link to the page to the hovering icons of each pin?

Comment: For example, you go to the site, it shows on the top left Indian Island Site as the title, you can click that to go to read more. I want to try to copy the link to the hovering box as well so mobile users can navigate without that large hovering box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $et_location_lat = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_et_listing_lat', true );
    $et_location_lng = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_et_listing_lng', true );

    $et_location_rating = '<div class="location-rating"></div>';
    if ( ( $et_rating = et_get_rating() ) && 0 != $et_rating )
        $et_location_rating = '<div class="location-rating"><span class="et-rating"><span style="' . sprintf( 'width: %dpx;', esc_attr( $et_rating * 17 ) ) . '"></span></span></div>';

    if ( '' != $et_location_lat && '' != $et_location_lng ) {
?>
        et_add_marker( <?php printf( '%1$d, %2$s, %3$s, \'<div id="et_marker_%1$d" class="et_marker_info"><div class="location-description"> <div class="location-title"><h2><a href="%6$s">%4$s</a></h2><div class="listing-info"><p>%5$s</p></div> </div> ' . $et_location_rating . ' </div> <!-- .location-description --> </div> <!-- .et_marker_info -->\'',
                $i,
                esc_html( $et_location_lat ),
                esc_html( $et_location_lng ),
                get_the_title(),
                wp_strip_all_tags( addslashes( get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'listing_type', '', ', ' ) ) ),
                get_the_permalink()
            ); ?> );
<?php
    }

    $i++;
endwhile;

rewind_posts();
?>
```

I added the link inside the title and then used [`get_the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/) function to pull the permalink in.